# About the definition of the notion of convergence for the sequence $(x_{α})_{α}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let us consider a real sequence $(x_{α})_{α}$ where $α$ is a multi-index (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation).

My **question** is about the definition of the notion of convergence for the sequence $(x_{α})_{α}$.

Example: $$x_{(n,m)}=1/m+1/n$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that one would define this as follows.

The real sequence $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_0^k}$ converges to the real number $L$ if $\forall \epsilon\gt0$ there exists $(N,N,\dots,N)\in\mathbb{N}_0^k$ such that $\alpha\gt(N,N,\dots,N)\implies|x_\alpha-L|\lt\epsilon$

For the example case we have that $x_{(n,m)}\to0$ as $\forall\epsilon\gt0$ we have that if $(n,m)\gt\left(\left\lceil\frac2{\epsilon}\right\rceil,\left\lceil\frac2{\epsilon}\right\rceil\right)$ then 
$$\begin{align}
|x_{(n,m)}-0|
&=\left|\frac1m+\frac1n\right|\\
&\le \left|\frac1m\right|+\left|\frac1n\right|\\
&=\frac1m+\frac1n\\
&\lt\frac{\epsilon}2+\frac{\epsilon}2\\
&=\epsilon\\
\end{align}$$